# How to replace address with selenium webdriver module in python without close then open browser?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a for loop in my source code, This loop include codes that test URLs in a List; of course for the test it needs open browser but doing this work is enough just for 1 time, in second time the robot should just replace address...

This is my source :

```
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[2] == '--smart':
        telerikbugtag = "Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau"
        telerikuiVul = '{ "message" : "RadAsyncUpload handler is registered succesfully, however, it may not be accessed directly." }'
        fopenAddr = open("clean url.txt", "r")
        addrlist = fopenAddr.read().split('\n')
        addrlistcln = list(filter(str.strip, addrlist))
        fopenAddr.close()

        for i in tqdm(addrlistcln):
            # Hey Mahdi!!!! I think you see that you did wrong now! Be A God ! AllRight?! ;)
            try:
                try:
                    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                    req = requests.get(i)
                    if req.status_code == 200 or req.status_code == 404:
                        browser.get(i)
                        time.sleep(4)
                        RedURL = browser.current_url
                        browser.close()

                        splitADR = RedURL.split('/')

                        filteredADR = list(filter(str.strip, splitADR))

                        if len(filteredADR) > 3:
                            reqadd = str(RedURL.replace(
                                str(RedURL).split('/').pop(), ""))
                        elif len(filteredADR) == 3:
                            reqadd = filteredADR[0] + '//' + \
                                filteredADR[1] + '/' + filteredADR[2] + '/'
                        else:
                            reqadd = filteredADR[0] + '//' + \
                                filteredADR[1] + '/'
                        reqHome = RedURL.split('/')
                        requthat = requests.get(reqadd + telerikbugtag)
                        regSoup = BeautifulSoup(
                            requthat.content, 'html.parser')
                        browser.close()

                        secondtest = requests.get(
                            reqHome[0] + "//" + reqHome[2] + '/' + telerikbugtag)
                        soupsec = BeautifulSoup(
                            secondtest.content, 'html.parser')

                        if telerikuiVul in regSoup and telerikuiVul not in soupsec:
                            fopenvul = open("vul list.txt", "a+")
                            fopenvul.write(reqadd + telerikbugtag + "\n")
                            fopenvul.close()
                        else:
                            print('\n' + i + ' NOT VUL :( ')

                    else:
                        print("Site Unavailable!")
                except Exception as er:
                    print('\n error... \n')
            except Exception as e:
                print("Site Error!")

    else:
        if(sys.argv[1] != '-h'):
            print("use '<Python3 source.py -h>' command")
        else:
            print('You are see Usage of This Script!')
```

help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the browser creation and closing out of the for loop

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for uri in ("http://www.python.org", "http://www.google.es", "http://www.google.com"):
    driver.get(uri)
    assert "Python" in driver.title or "Google" in driver.title
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

Comment: Script stopped; and I should press Ctrl+C for exit program

Comment: You can see full of the source in : https://pastebin.pl/view/dee5a2d7

Comment: sorry I can't help you to debug your problem, I will paste the answer to your question as an example, I've tested and it works, I hope it helps you